# Ошибка Consider defining a bean of type 'com.example.here.repository.PostRepositroy' in your configuration

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

Заметил, что ошибка проходит только при создании репозитория (закомментировал GetMapping, но ошибка осталась та же. Если закомментировать весь контроллер, то ошибка исчезает)

BlogController:

```
package com.example.here.controller;

import com.example.here.entity.Post;
import com.example.here.repository.PostRepositroy;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;

@Controller
public class BlogController {
    @Autowired()
    private PostRepositroy postRepository;

    @GetMapping("/blog")
    public String Blog (Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("title", "Блог");

        Iterable<Post> posts = postRepository.findAll();

        model.addAttribute("posts", posts);

        return("blog-main");
    }
}
```

PostRepository:

```
package com.example.here.repository;

import com.example.here.entity.Post;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

@Repository
public interface PostRepositroy extends JpaRepository<Post, Long>{
}
```

Application.java:

```
package com.example.here;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.domain.EntityScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;

@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan("com.example.here")
@EntityScan("com.example.here.entity")
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "com.example.here.entity")
public class HereIStudyTogetherYoutubeApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(HereIStudyTogetherYoutubeApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Сущность поста:

```
package com.example.here.entity;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
import lombok.*;
import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.persistence.Entity;

@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@Table(name = "blog")
public class Post {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @JsonIgnore
    private Long id;

    private String title, anons, full_text;
    private int views;



}
```

Ошибка:

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Field postRepository in com.example.here.controller.BlogController required a bean of type 'com.example.here.repository.PostRepositroy' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
    - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.example.here.repository.PostRepositroy' in your configuration.


Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Бин репозитория не находится. Скорее всего есть какие-то ошибки при указании путей в многочисленных аннотациях над `Main`-классом. Уберите их все, кроме `@SpringBootApplication`.

Comment: Где-то в конфигурации надо но поделить Бин репозитория, таковое акция рекомендуется. Но этого наверно будет мало, потому что могут быть ошибки в самом репозитории, а подключить репозиторий с ошибками не получится, поэтому оно не работает.